# Paste Special Gone from Visual Studio 2012

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio-2012, paste

This is really weird.  I have an ASP project.  I wanted to copy text from an email into the ASPX page (designer view).  So, I opened the email, copied the text (CTRL-C) and pasted it into the page.  It looked nice, but looking at the source I saw that it flooded the page with MS Word style CSS.  So, I undid it.  I right-clicked the page, tried Paste, and got the same result (expected).  Undid, then tried "Paste Special".  I was pleasantly surprised when I saw several choices, including something like, Paste as plain text, but keep line feeds.  I used that and it worked perfectly.  I was happy!
I get another email and go to do the same thing.  I open the email, select the text, Copy (CTRL-C) and go to Visual Studio to paste.  Only now, Paste Special is gone!  I have Paste, which throws in all of the MS Word CSS again and "Paste Alternate" which rips out all of the line feeds and formatting.  There is no more Paste Special!
What the heck happened in the hour between the two emails to make Visual Studio change it's context menu and replace "Paste Special" with the useless "Paste Alternate"?  How do I get Paste Special back??

Comment: It probably depends on where you right-click

Comment: Also, ASP Classic != ASP.Net.

Comment: ASP.NET.  I've clicked in the same place (designer screen) inside the DIV area, outside the DIV area, and in the Source.  "Paste Special" is just gone!